# Apple Mach-O Linker Error occurs after adding AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

When I add AFNetworking and build, Apple Mach-O Linker Error occur.
I saw Similar Questions but I couldn't any hints.

I added AFNetworking which is downloaded from GitHub to project.
The error message:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already added following frameworks.
・CFNetwork.framework
・Accelerate.framework
・SystemConfiguration.framework
・MobileCoreServices.framework
・Security.framework
・SenTestingKit.framework

How do I do to build?

By the way, I found description `#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>` in files of AFNetworking, but such framework is not found in Xcode.
Is this alright?

Comment: Are you using the newest version of Xcode?

Comment: Are you building for OS X or iOS?